# Updating a value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a data table of which I want to update employees salaries by adding an additional 5000 to all those who earn less than 30 000.

this is what I did and even thought there is not any errors the actual update does not take place.

Advice perhaps?

```
 string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=lrmg;Integrated Security=True;";

        using (sqlConnect = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            sqlConnect.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = sqlConnect.CreateCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Employee] SET [Salary] += 5000 WHERE [Salary] < 30000";

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            sqlConnect.Close();
        }


        labMessage.Text = "The update was processed";
```

Comment: Do you have a Salary in your table that is less then 3000? Check the number of 0's.

Comment: maybe only a typo, but you update all which have a salary under 3000 :)

Comment: After so many C# SQL questions being asked here, why are the *still* people not using `using`? I bet you're also not using parameterized queries? ;-)

Comment: I am new at the using keyword. Is it only used when new keyword calls the constructor of an object?

Comment: You need to figure out what the query is actually doing.  There are lots of tools that will help you determine that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `< 30.000` value then :-)

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Employee] SET [Salary] = [Salary] + 5000 WHERE [Salary] < 30000";
```

Answer (score 3):

small typo its 30000 you say, you had 3000..

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Employee] SET [Salary] += 5000 WHERE [Salary] < 30000";
```

note to self, += is now a valid operator as of 5 years ago ^^

Comment: But why [**`+=`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627392%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) in the OP doesn't work? it should work properly.

Comment: unless it was added recently += is not a valid transact-sql operator

Comment: @jenson-button-event It's valid as of mssql 2008

Comment: The question is tagged with SQL Server 2008, and it is valid in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: ach, must read release notes more carefully - some bad habits die hard. sql been making me do dirty vb style since 1996